# .NET Reflector MSIL

Tags: silverlight-4.0, ria, reflector

Looking at the AuthorizedChangeSet Method which reflector shows as

```
protected virtual bool AuthorizeChangeSet()
    {
        foreach (ChangeSetEntry entry in this.ChangeSet.ChangeSetEntries)
        {
            object entity = entry.Entity;
            if (entry.DomainOperationEntry != null)
            {
                this.ValidateMethodPermissions(entry.DomainOperationEntry, entity);
            }
            if ((entry.EntityActions != null) && entry.EntityActions.Any<KeyValuePair<string, object[]>>())
            {
                KeyValuePair<string, object[]> pair = entry.EntityActions.Single<KeyValuePair<string, object[]>>();
                DomainOperationEntry customMethod = this.ServiceDescription.GetCustomMethod(entity.GetType(), pair.Key);
                this.ValidateMethodPermissions(customMethod, entity);
            }
        }
        return !this.ChangeSet.HasError;
    }
```

How is it possible to access properties of the entity object in the foreach loop when its cast as object???

Answer (score 0):

Read carefully, it does not. It only accesses members of entry and not entity.
Another option could be that ValidateMethodPermissions use reflection